# Словообразование глагола "разбежаться"

Tags: словообразование

Скажите, пожалуйста, каким способом образовано слово "разбежаться"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Слово разбежаться образовано от глагола бежать пристаточно-суффиксальным способом. Точнее,  приставочно-постфиксальным.